# Selenium - How to count the number of rows in a table?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-ide

I have a table with "n" number of rows. I need to count them, how to do?

Example:- My table looks like the below entry.

```
Type        Balance Date received       Date returned   Payment method  Amount
General     Default 10/01/2013 08:53:20                 Cash            $ 10.00

HTML of my table looks like this. <th> is table title row and <td> are the entries done by the user. Everytime the user add the new entry, the count will increase and display a message "3 found for account 6478 ". where 3 is no of rows in the table.   
<fieldset>
<table id="listBalances" class="listTable" width="100%">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Type</th>
<th>Balance</th>
<th>Date received</th>
<th>Date returned</th>
<th>Payment method</th>
<th>Amount</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr class="alt">
<td>General Deposit</td>
<td>Default for RTB</td>
<td>09/30/2013 06:58:41</td>
<td/>
<td>Cash</td>
<td>$ 5.00</td>
```

Comment: please, provide some code representing your table to provide you proper selectors.

Comment: please also clarify which language you are using (Java) and if you are using WebDriver or not (Selenium IDE?).

Comment: Java and Selenium IDE.

Answer (score 0):

To store Number of rows into table you can use `storeXpathCount`

```
storeXpathCount | id=listBalances | NumberOfRows
echo  | ${NumberOfRows}
```

storeXpathCount will store rows count into variable NumberOfRows
And echo will return count.

Answer (score -3):

I would suggest the following:

1) make list of elements of your table (e.g if you need to count your row count then select any row using appropriate selector).

2) then create list of web elements

```
List<WebElement> columnElments = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("...blablabla..."));
int rowNumer = columnElmments.size();
```

or either:

```
@FindBy
            (how = How.CSS, using = "blablablba")
List<WebElement> col;

int rowNumer =col.size();
```

Hope you got the idea

Comment: unfortunately this is useless if he is using Selenium IDE.

Comment: also, you could shorten that code to `int size = driver.findElements().size()`