# Selenium IDE: Get row count in table

Tags: selenium, testing, automated-tests, selenium-ide

How do I get the row count of a given table using the Selenium IDE?

When I right click on my table, I can only assert/verify the following:

- Title
- Value
- Text
- Table
- Element Present

with the target being

```
//div[@id='reports']/div[n]` where `n` is the number of rows.
```

Comment: Did you try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155430/selenium-how-to-count-the-number-of-rows-in-a-table

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio I did and both answers there are irrelevant. One is for Selenium WebDriver and the other is either outdated or incorrect. Though I just figured out a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the `storeXpathCount` command. This takes two parameters which can be stored within the IDE `Target` and `Value` fields where the following parameters are,  respectively:

- **xpath**: the xpath expression to evaluate
- **variableName**

Here is an example where the table `id = reports`:

```
Command: storeXpathCount
Target: //div[@id='reports']/div[n]/table/tbody/tr
Value: myVarCount
```

where `n` in `div[n]` from above is your div number.

*Hint: Right click on your table with Selenium IDE open to quickly get the path!*